# CodeIgniter model not loading correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter, function, model, controller

I am writting my first CodeIgniter script and I can't get the following model to load, if anyone could maybe help me?

Here is my controller file:

```
public function process(){
// Load the model
$this->load->model('users/login', 'users');

// Validate the user can login
$result = $this->users->validate();

// Now we verify the result
if(!$result){
    // If user did not validate, then show them login page again
    $this->index();
}else{
    // If user did validate,
    // Send them to members area
    redirect('home');
}      
}
```

And here is my model

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Login_Model extends CI_Model{
    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function validate(){

        // grab user input
        $username = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('username'));
        $password = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('password'));

        // Prep the query
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);

        // Run the query
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        // Let's check if there are any results
        if($query->num_rows == 1)
        {
            // If there is a user, then create session data
            $row = $query->row();
            $data = array(
                    'userid' => $row->userid,
                    'fname' => $row->fname,
                    'lname' => $row->lname,
                    'username' => $row->username,
                    'validated' => true
                    );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            return true;
        }
        // If the previous process did not validate
        // then return false.
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

I can confirm the the process function is loading however any code that goes underneath the $results = $result = $this->users->validate(); doesn't appear. The model is also loading,  it is as soon as I try call a function, the script kills itself.

Sorry if this question is a little bland.

Thanks
Peter

Comment: Maybe the issue is happening bcs of security library, which you're using in model, but there is no code to load it.

Comment: I am loading the model with this code $this->load->model('users/login', 'users'); which is posted above the in the controller section. The model seems to be loading, the script is killing itself when it reaches the $result = $this->users->validate();

Comment: You can use `$this->input->post('some_data', TRUE);` // The second optional parameter lets you run the data through the XSS filter. It's enabled by setting the second parameter to boolean TRUE;

Comment: Thanks, I tried that just there, that didn't do anything. I even created a public function test() with it saying echo 'test'; and tried to load that but still no luck :(

Comment: "the srcript kills itself" .... any error message?

Comment: nope,  and I am using development enviroment :(

Comment: Try print_r($this->input->post()) in controller, and then in validate() in model...

Comment: wait,  just inserted ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 ini_set('log_errors', 1);
 ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);  that has came up with some problems!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all came down to my code.  Your models class name must be equal to the name of the model file.

So in this case, I should have named my file login_model.php and then the class itself must be called Login_model (the first character must be uppercase, all other characters must be lowercase). When calling the model in the controller it must all be lower case like:

```
$this->load->model('login_model');
```

Hope this is help to anyone in the future, thanks to all for the efforts and comments :)

Comment: As an added comment, your class name can be any sort of uppercase/lowercase mix but CodeIgniter will return an object variable named in lowercase. For instance, if your class is called LoginModel, you must call it with `$this->loginmodel`. This goes for loading libraries as well.

Answer (score 0):

You try capitalize the name of your file?
user_model.php to User_model.php?